# Separate Date and Time objects

Tags: java, date, time

I have a web-form where users can select a date from a calendar pop-up and a time from a dropdown. At the moment I am trying to store the date using a Date object.

```
@Required
public Date date;
```

And the output of this object is something like:

> January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

What I would really like to do is separate this and store the date in a format like *27/02/2013* and have the time as a separate object in 24 hour format e.g. *23:45*. I am unsure how to do this with java.

Resolved using SimpleDateFormat:

```
//also the import
import java.text.*;

@Required
public SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
public String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

@Required
public SimpleDateFormat simpleTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
public String time = simpleTimeFormat.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `Calendar` class. It has all of the methods required to get different "date parts". Also, look at the `SimpleDateFormat` class in java to format the date in needed way.

Calendar - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

SimpleDateFormat - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I used the SimpleDateFormat and updated my answer to include my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

String dateAsString = dateFormatter.format(date);
String timeAsString = timeFormatter.format(date);
```